# Difficulty running OwinHost from the command line

Tags: host, owin

I have been working through various OWIN tutorials and have consistently encountered the same problem; the applications work fine when I launch them from within Visual Studio (2013) using F5, but when I navigate via the command line to Owinhost.exe and launch it, I get the same error every time:

Error:  System.EntryPointNotFoundException

The following errors occurred while attempting to load the app.

- No assembly found containing an OwinStartupAttribute.
- No assembly found containing a Startup or [AssemblyName].Startup class.

Of the various suggestions online, I have:

1) Made sure that the output directory is just "/bin" and not "/bin/debug".

2) Defined the assembly in my startup class:

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(StartUpDemo.Startup))]
```

3) Set my web.config

```
<appSettings>
<add key="owin:AppStartup" value="StartUpDemo.Startup"/>
</appSettings>
```

4) I have also tried disabling OWIN startup discovery using appSetting owin:AutomaticAppStartup with a value of "false" all to no avail.

It seems like OwinHost.exe is not even finding my application .dll, but as I mentioned before, it works fine in VS2013 when I launch it from within the IDE. I have changed the project settings in the "web" tab to use OwinHost, but otherwise the project setup is normal. Does VS2013 have information that I need to pass into the command line to get it to work correctly? Am I missing something in my configuration?

Comment: Which directory are you in the console when you try to launch owinhost.exe? Owinhost.exe can discover startup classes when you have start up classes in the current folder when the current folder is 'bin' or you are at the web application folder and executing something like this c:\MyProjects\MyWebApp>..\packages\Owinhost<version>\tools\Owinhost.exe.

Comment: I am doing the latter. I would add that my start up class is also in the 'bin' folder as you suggest. I just tried navigating to the bin directory and then launching OwinHost.exe from there--that worked, but that doesn't seem to be how it is supposed to work.

Comment: You don't have to navigate to the bin folder, but navigate to its parent folder and executing Owinhost in the bin's parent folder should work. I just mentioned executing from the bin folder also works. Alternatively Owinhost.exe has a -d parameter which can take in a target folder path to search for startup class.

Comment: @Praburaj I have issue in Owinhost.exe when I try to execute in command prompt with my OwinStartup class with OwinStartup attribute then got message. "Error:  System.EntryPointNotFoundException"
The following errors occurred while attempting to load the app. please reply me if any solution you have!

Answer (score 4):

Well, I don't know if this question has already been answered but anyway I had the same issue when trying to run through Owinhost.

The problem was that I was trying to run Owinhost in the ..\tools\ path. Actually what have to be done is be in the project path (Eg. Project.Web) and being at this path run the Owinhost calling: "..\packages\OwinHost.\tools\OwinHost.exe"

**Conclusion:**

Wrong:

```
C:\{your_root_path}\{your_solution}\packages\OwinHost.<version>\tools> OwinHost.exe
```

Correct:

`C:\{your_root_path}\{your_solution}\{your_project}> ..\packages\OwinHost.<version>\tools\OwinHost.exe`

Hope I have helped. Regards.

Comment: This is just a way to run `OwinHost.exe` with the target argument set to the current directory (which is the project folder). The important thing here is the target path is exactly ***the project folder***, not including the ***/bin*** path which is the main reason causing the `OwinHost.exe` not to find any entry assembly. So it's very confusing here, because the target path should end at the ***/bin*** folder (containing the app's 
 assemblies). You can always specify the target path for `OwinHost.exe` using `-d` parameter so you can run `OwinHost.exe` from wherever you want.

Comment: This was the only way to run it (well, without copying everything from the OwinHost's install location in the solution's packages directory).  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Go to this folder OwinHost.3.1.0\tools  and copy everything and put in application folder.
Now OwinHost will work

Comment: I can't undo my -1 without giving a +1...Microsoft needs to fix their installs -> their documentation is currently in a state where the OwinHost doesn't work directly.  The best solution here is to go to the project root and call the install location from there, as in dime2lo's comment above.  Moving the install directory around will result in very hard to understand solutions later by programmers coming in to projects.
Having to move installs around is bad practice / takes files out of package management.